# The compiler failed with error code 128

Tags: .net, iis-6

I have a windows 2003 server running IIS 6.
IIS has roughly 120 sites running on it.

I have had the "The compiler failed with error code 128" with one specific site this morning, tried creating its own Application Pool, restarted the site, can seem to get anything to work.

There is no virus protection program running on the server and I would prefer to not have to run anything on the server.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: how can I get my site to run again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: Fixed with a full server restart. Though I am still unaware of how this originally occurred.